# Host multiple application under single domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

Currently I develop new app for my customer and need to integrate it with the old one.
My current app based on `Ruby 1.9.3` and latest Rails version. Old app written on `Ruby 1.8.7` and something like `rails 3.0.11.`

So my goal is to host it under one domain, so if `localhost/old_controller` will bring customer to some old controller, and `localhost/new_controller` will be handled by my application. Is it possible and how to do that? Or if it's not possible, then handle new app as a sub domain for the old one, like `localhost` for old one and `new.localhost` for my app.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Rails Engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html). Basically they are Rails Applications which can be hooked to another application.

As for the authlogic matter: If both of your apps share the **same** database then there shouldn't be a problem regarding the logins - provided you use gems in both apps that share the same schema they're built on.

Comment: The old app use standard rails auth mechanism, and it's strongly undesirable for me to change it. It's almost impossible. So I need the way to connect rails auth mechanisms, but from different versions. But thx for your tip, I take a look to engines.